# RabbitMQ Work-Queue for FanOut messaging

Tags: rabbitmq, exchange-server, amqp

I'm trying to scale-out a RabbitMQ messaging system. The current system is very simple - the producer sends a message to a fanout  exchange and the message is handle by multiple consumers  - classic fanout routing .

I have multiple consumers from different types (e.g: one that print to screen, one that logs to file, one that saves to DB,...).
My challenge - i'm not sure what's  the best way to scale-out the consumers. If i add other consumers from the same type - i'll get double logs or double entries in the DB. ... (think about two DB consumers consuming from the same fanout exchange) .

I guess I can create a consumer that publish to a work-queue but I wonder if there's a better "builtin" solution in rabbitmq.

thanks in advance,
zf

Answer (score 0):

If you need to scale consumers in order to consume faster all the messages coming from the fanout exchange you need competive consuming; so you need more consumers attached to the same queue bound to the fanout exchange.
In this way every consumer will consume a batch of messages indipendently from the others. The number of messages inside the batch is defined with the prefetch count property ( http://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html ).
In this way, in your case, you should be able to scale consumers avoiding double logs and double entries in the DB.

Comment: That's obvious, so I guess I wasn't clear...I apologize. The question is how to scale while making sure that from each type of consumers only one will process . If I have two types of consuners, type1 and type2 and I want that each message will be handled by each type but only once per type . I can create a fanout exchange that will send to 2 work queues....Is there another option ?

Comment: I don't know if I am understanding correctly your request but if you want a fanout exchange with each consumer with its own queue bound to it, there's no way to ensure that a single message is processed only from one consumer.

The only way I see that allows to scale consumers and be sure that only one of them consumes a message is to have all the consumers on a single queue bound to the exchange (and in that case it could be direct, there's no need of a fanout).

But, maybe I don't get completely the point, sorry if my answer doesn't help you much :-)

Comment: ` I can create a fanout exchange that will send to 2 work queues....Is there another option ?` <-- Why? this pattern does exactly what are you looking for. Why do you need another way! I maybe didn't get your problem!

Comment: Gabrielle, I was looking for another way since i assumed that there is a better way. It sounds like a very standard scenario (especially with today's microservices) so i hoped that there is a "builtin pattern" . anyhow, thank you all !! i guess that the only way to achieve my goal is indeed a fanout (so that many handlers/consumers will accept the message) but then route to a working-queue (so only one handler per type will handle an incoming message) .

Comment: I'm pretty much facing the same challenge (indeed microservices architecture) and i think that i can explain why the proposed solution is not optimql.